# how to change caption of button present on MFC dialog box

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I have a MFC dialog box with small text box and button for ok and cancel. Now in some cases I want to change caption of OK and CANCEL button to YES and NO. Is there a way to do this outside of OnInitdialog method of CDialog class

Thanks
Niraj Rathi

Answer (score 5):

You can change those text at any moment (when the dialog window exists) with `SetWindowText` function, e.g.:

```
GetDlgItem(IDOK)->SetWindowText("Yes");
```

Comment: When I do this from View class program crashes but when I add the line you said in above answer, in InitDialog mehtod it works. I would prefer code for this to be in View class. So in view I create object of dialog and then on that object invoke GetDlgItem and then SetWindowText